# How to build a program with multiple files whith inter files function calls with makefile in C

Tags: c, file, gcc, makefile, build

I am struggling with building a program with multiple files whith inter files function calls with makefile in C. Let's say that I have a main file which call a function `call_print_hello()` declared in a header file `fdeclar_macros.h` and written in the file `script1.c`. The function `call_print_hello()` itself calls another function `print_hello()` also declared in `fdeclar_macros.h` and written in `script2.c`. I have also a `makefile` but when I run it I get the following error message:

```
gcc  -g -Wall -c main.c
gcc  -g -Wall -c script1.c
gcc  -o main main.o script1.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_call_print_hello", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Here are the content of the files:

`makefile`:

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

main: main.o script1.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o script1.o 

main.o: main.c fdeclar_macros.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

script2.o: script2.c fdeclar_macros.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c script2.c

script1.o: script1.c fdeclar_macros.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c script1.c

run: main
    ./main

clean:
    $(RM) -rf justify *.dSYM *.o
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "fdeclar_macros.h"

int main(){
  call_print_hello();
  return 0;
}
```

`fdeclar_macros.h`:

```
#define NUMBER 3

void print_hello();
void call_print_hello();
```

`script1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fdeclar_macros.h"

void print_hello(){
  printf("hello %d\n", NUMBER);
}
```

`script2.c`:

```
#include "fdeclar_macros.h"

void call_print_hello(){
  print_hello();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make target for the `main` executable does not contain a dependency on `script2.o` and the rule to build `main` does not link `script2.o` into the `main` executable either.

So the linker tries to build an executable with the content of `script2.o` missing, but as that content is required, linking fails.

One easy fix would be to change the original rule

```
main: main.o script1.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o script1.o
```

by adding `script2.o`:

```
main: main.o script1.o script2.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o script1.o script2.o
```

I will leave finding more general rules as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

```
NAME = my_programm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
MY_SOURCES = main.c script1.c script2.c
MY_OBJECTS = $(MY_SOURCES:.c=.o)

$(NAME): $(MY_OBJECTS)
    @cc $(CFLAGS) $(MY_OBJECTS) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    @rm -f $(MY_OBJECTS)
    @rm -f $(NAME)

run:
    ./my_programm
```